# 2D initialization syntax in C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, malloc

Why doesn't the following work to initialise an array of long long ints in C:

```
int **m = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) m[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(long long int));
```

To work it has to be:

```
long long int **m = malloc(n * sizeof(long long int *));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) m[i] = malloc(n *sizeof(long long int));
```

I don't understand why the pointer to the long long ints does not fit in an int? It's just an address, right?

Comment: The pointers 'fit', but the interpretation of the pointers is wrong, so all hell breaks loose.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: pointer is just a pointer, why does it have to take as many bits as long long int * instead of just int *?

Comment: There is a difference between `int` and `long long int`. First example will work if you do `m[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @TomasGudmundsson The question in your comment makes no sense.

Comment: when calling `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the 2 fragments in your question initializes an *array* of `long long int`s.

- You merely allocate an array of pointers to arrays of `int` of `long long int` respectively, but none of these are initialized.
- The first fragment is inconsistent as you allocate memory for the second level arrays with a size of `n * sizeof(long long int)` instead of `n * sizeof(int)`, but it will not cause problems since `long long int` cannot be smaller than `int`.
- The second fragment is more consistent, but you should use type `size_t` for the index `i` for complete consistency.

*pointer to the long long ints does not fit in an int? It's just an address, right?* :

- No, pointers indeed contain addresses, but may be larger than `int`. Most 64-bit systems have 32-bit `int` and 64-bit pointers.

Here are more reliable ways to allocate and initialize your 2D pseudo arrays:

```
// allocate and initialize the 2D indirect array
long long int **m = malloc(n * sizeof(*m));
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    m[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(*m[i]));
}

// allocate and initialize a 2D indirect array with a single chunk
long long int **m = malloc(n * sizeof(*m));
m[0] = calloc(n * n, sizeof(*m[0]));
for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    m[i] = m[i - 1] + n;
}

// allocate and initialize a flat 2D array:
long long int m[n][n] = calloc(1, sizeof(m));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the size of the pointer, it's the type associated with it. When your allocation has finished, which is completely fine, as long as you use `m` as a matrix of `int`s, you will eventually write something like this:

```
long long int myLongLongInt = 1234567;
m[row][col] = myLongLongInt;
```

This is where the problem is, because `m[row][col]` is an *lvalue* of integer type, not `long long int` type. Two adjacent elements of `m`'s row are `sizeof(int)` apart, not `sizeof(long long int)`. Hence the assignment will not work correctly.